# Hello world rails app with dropzonejs-rails file upload option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Followed this simple `hello world` and created app https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2013/11/24/saying-hello-world-with-ruby-on-rails.html . Then trying to
add file upload using `dropzonejs-rails`

```
$cat app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    puts "Honey, I'm home!"
  end
end

$ cat  app/views/pages/home.html.erb
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

 <form action="/fileupload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"> </form>


$ cat config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

Added `dropzonejs-rails` entries to Gemfile and application.js

```
$ grep dropzonejs-rails Gemfile
gem 'dropzonejs-rails'

$ grep dropzone app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require dropzone
```

On the web page I can upload the file but unable to save it. Since I'm not sure how to provide
that.  It errors out like `Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/fileupload"`

How to resolve this issue. thanks in advance.

Edit: @Vasilisa Prefer to store files on some directory under file system. (/some/path/uploadedfiles)

Comment: Where do you want to save the image? You need to create corresponding model and use uploader (like built in ActiveStorage or Carrierwave or something else). And you need a separate action in controller - you specified `action="/fileupload"`, but you haven't such action and route. Check this [chapter](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) of Rails Guides at first, you'll find all answers, I hope

Comment: Run `bundle install` after modifying the `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yes, I did ran `bundle install` .okay, Let  me check action/route for `/fileupload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to make the route, even though something like `/fileupload` is really non-RESTful.

I tend to have a resource set up like so:

```
resources :attachments
```

With a matching class to handle the uploaded object.

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :data
end
```

You'll need a controller, too.

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_attachment, only: :index
  before_action :set_attachment, except: %i[show destroy]

  def index
    render json: { images: @attachments }.to_json
  end

  def create
    if @attachment.update_attributes!(attachment_params)
      render json: { attachment: @attachment }, status: 200
    else
      render json: { error: @attachment.errors }, status: 400
    end
  end

  def show
    render json: { attachment: @attachment }.to_json
  end

  def update
    if @attachment.update_attributes!(attachment_params)
      render json: { attachment: @attachment }.to_json
    else
      render json: { error: @attachment.errors }, status: 400
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @attachment.destroy
      render json: { message: 'success' }, status: 200
    else
      render json: { message: @attachment.errors }, status: 400
    end
  end
end
```

That way you're in keeping with the Rails OOP logic. Your route will change, though, from `/fileupload` to `/attachments`.